# passing Header JWT Token with Axios & React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt

first of all, postman works just fine:
[image]

I have my api called

```js
const api = http://localhost:4000/here
```

And I am trying to make a get request using Axios and I am using this code:

```js
const request = (data) => {
    return axios
        .get(api, { headers: authHeader() },
            { data: data }
        )
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.accessToken) {
                console.log(response.data)
                localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
            }

            return response.data;
        });
};

console.log(request.id)
```

this is the `authHeader`

```js
export default function authHeader() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    if (user && user.accessToken) {
        return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

and result of the `console.log` comes out as `undefined`
can anyone tell me why? thank you

Comment: This seems like a CORS issue. Do you have the error response from the request?

Comment: You should go into network tab in your browser devtools, and see where the request is failing. Or check your console tab